# How do I create datapoints based on user-set time periods with queried MYSQL data?

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a database management system. The user may set varying time periods from a day to years. Each entry is time stamped. How do I divide up time periods into data points for a graph(using the google graphs api) without hardcoding all of it? I am using a MYSQL database, and mainly php.

```
<form name="dateChanger" method="POST" style="padding:10px;" border="1">
Enter the Range of Dates You'd Like. <br>
Please Note that if you want 1 day, enter the date you want in the start date in btoh fields<br>
This checks the following Ranges: Day, Week, 2 weeks, 3 weeks, 1-11 months, 1-5 years
Start Date: <input name="startmonth" size=2 type="textbox" maxlength=2>/<input name="startday" size=2 type="textbox" maxlength=2>/<input name="startyear" size=4 type="textbox" maxlength=4><br><br>
End Date:  <input name="endmonth" size=2 type="textbox" maxlength=2>/<input name="endday" size=2 type="textbox" maxlength=2>/<input name="endyear" size=4 type="textbox" maxlength=4><br><br>
<input name="submitbtn2" type="submit">
</form>
```

So with this code you can pick the range. Is there a framework or something that lets me pick the data points. For instance, how many phones were sold in July. I'd probably have a data point for each day. But if they change the date range to 6 months, then I'd probably have a data point(as in number phones sold) for every 2 weeks. How do I code all of this? There's definitely something out there to help.

Comment: this is too broad / prone to opinionated answers to address in one question. you need to make an attempt and then let us know what isn't working for you. good rule of thumb, if you can show us code then we're more likely to be able to help.

Comment: okay I added more so it is more clear. Thanks

Comment: still too much open to interpretation, but this might give you some ideas. save the data in your datastore at the lowest common denominator (smallest date interval). then aggregate in chart. Here's a SO topic regarding data in this format being used in a google chart: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717574/how-to-seperate-dates-by-year-in-google-line-chart This comment is just food for thought and not a good answer for the reasons mentioned above. good luck with your design and post new questions if you run into issues